# Showing that if $N$ is minimal normal and $NH=G$, then $H$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'd appreciate input on the validity of this proof.  It feels good to me, but I like knowing for sure and have no one else to get input from.

Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.  Assume that $N$ is abelian, let $H<G$ be a proper subgroup, and assume that $NH = G$.  Show that $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

I am given the hint that if $X \le G$ is any subgroup of $G$ such that $NX=G$, then $N \cap X \triangleleft G$.  (I was able to work this out for myself.)

Since $NH=G$ we must have (by the result in the hint) $N \cap H =1$, for otherwise $N \cap H$ would be a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $N$, contradicting our assumption that $N$ is minimal normal.  Since $N \cap H=1$, it follows that $|G|=|NH|=\frac{|N||H|}{|N \cap H|}=|N||H|$.

Suppose that $K<G$ contains $H$, $H \le K$.  Since $H \le K$ and $NH=G$, we also have that $NK=G$.  But for the same reason given above for $H$, we must have $|G|=|N||K|$.  Then $|G|=|N||H|=|N||K|$ implies $|H|=|K|$, so $H=K$ and $H$ is maximal in $G$.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems OK, but you should really consider the possibility $N \cap H = N$ (and similarly for $K$). That would imply $H=G$ contradicting $H < G$.

Comment: I did overlook that...  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Derek Holt mentions in the comments, it seems okay, but you should consider the case $N \cap H = N$.

You are also assuming that $G$ is finite. This is not necessary. For a proof that works in general, you can apply following statement, which is very easy to prove but useful.

> (Dedekind's modular law) If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are subgroups such that $B \leq A$, then $B(C \cap A) = BC \cap A$.

Using the notation of your question, let $M$ some subgroup such that $H \leq M \leq G$. Since $G = NH = HN$, we have $M = HN \cap M = H(N \cap M)$. Now $N \cap M$ is a normal subgroup by your hint, so it follows that $M = H$ or $M = G$ because $N$ is minimal normal.

Comment: I like that use of Dedekind's Lemma.  Thanks for the help.